# Jquery search on JSON Arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
<script>
var data = [
      {
        "BP": "Title",
        "Attr": ["Attr 1", "Attr2"],
        "Tables": ["Fact", "Fact", "Fact", "Fact", "Fact"],
        "Vendor": ["Vendor1"],
        "BO": ["Vxy", "XYZ"]
      },
      {
        "BP": "KYB",
        "Attr": ["Attr 1", "Attr2"],
        "Tables": ["Data Not Persisted"],
        "Vendor": ["LX"],
        "BO": ["JXA", "HJZ"]
      }];

      $(document).ready(function() {

        $.ajaxSetup({
          cache: false
        });

        $('#search').keyup(function() {

          $('#result').html('');
          $('#state').val('');

          var searchField = $('#search').val();

          // i makes the search case insensitive
          var expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");

          console.log(expression)

          $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            if (value.BP.search(expression) != -1 || value.Tables.search(expression) != -1) {
              $('#result').append('<li class="list-group-item link-class">' + value.Vendor + '|<span class="text-muted">' + value.BP + '|<span class="text-muted">' + value.Tables + '</li>');
              //console.log(value.Tables);
            }
          });
        });

        $('#result').on('click', 'li', function() {
          var click_text = $(this).text().split('|');
          $('#search').val($.trim(click_text[0]));
          $("#result").html('');
        });
      }); 
</script>
```

I am trying to attempt a Live JSON search on my JSON Object. It works on attributes that have only 1 element but fails when some attribute such as "Tables" have an array of elements.

I get the following exception.

> value.Tables.search is not a function
>       at Object. (test_ds.html:173)
>       at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at HTMLInputElement. (test_ds.html:172)
>       at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
>       at HTMLInputElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)

Comment: where is the code that has `value.Tables.search`?

Comment: the basic HTML associated with this question would also be helpful, even if it is only a `div` and an `input`.  I echo the need for the failing code.

Comment: My Bad. I have edited the code snippet and added the code for table search.

Answer (score 0):

### Iteration over Array of strings

The `Tables` variable should be accessed in parts because accessing it as a whole will return an array.

I don't know where your `value.Tables.search` code is, however, you can replace it with something like the following:

```
value.Tables.some(table => table.search(....))
```

This works because `.some` returns true if any of the strings in `Tables` pass the conditional function, in your case this is `.search`

Answer (score 0):

First of all **this is a Javascript `array` and not a JSON array**.

Second thing you don't need to use jQuery to search for a `string` in an `array`, you can profit from all [**Array** built-in methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). You can use [**`Array.filter()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) along with [**`Array.some()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to filter the items only containing the searched word.

This is a simple function that uses these two methods, to loop recursively over the `array` items, search for the word and return only items that contains it:

```
function searchWord(data, word) {
  return data.filter(function(item) {
    if (Array.isArray(item)) {
      return searchWord(item, word) && searchWord(item, word).length > 0;
    } else if (typeof item == 'string') {
      return item.indexOf(word) > -1;
    } else if (typeof item == 'object') {
      return Object.values(item).some(function(v) {
        if (Array.isArray(v)) {
          return searchWord(v, word).length > 0;
        } else if (typeof v == 'object') {
          return Object.values(v).some(val => val.indexOf(word) > -1);
        } else if (typeof v == 'string') {
          return v.indexOf(word) > -1;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      });
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

**Demo:**

This is a working Demo using this function.

```js
var data = [{
    "BP": "Title",
    "Attr": ["Attr 1", "Attr2"],
    "Tables": ["Fact", "Fact", "Fact", "Fact", "Fact"],
    "Vendor": ["Vendor1"],
    "BO": ["Vxy", "XYZ"]
  },
  {
    "BP": "KYB",
    "Attr": ["Attr 1", "Attr2"],
    "Tables": ["Data Not Persisted"],
    "Vendor": ["LX"],
    "BO": ["JXA", "HJZ"]
  }
];

function searchWord(data, word) {

  return data.filter(function(item) {
    if (Array.isArray(item)) {
      return searchWord(item, word) && searchWord(item, word).length > 0;
    } else if (typeof item == 'string') {
      return item.indexOf(word) > -1;
    } else if (typeof item == 'object') {
      return Object.values(item).some(function(v) {
        if (Array.isArray(v)) {
          return searchWord(v, word).length > 0;
        } else if (typeof v == 'object') {
          return Object.values(v).some(val => val.indexOf(word) > -1);
        } else if (typeof v == 'string') {
          return v.indexOf(word) > -1;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      });
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
}


console.log(searchWord(data, "Persisted"));
console.log(" --------- ****** ----------");
console.log(searchWord(data, "Vendor1"));
```